# Process Scheduler Simulation parsing input

Tags: c, io, scheduler

Im currently embarking on a simulation of a process scheduler using both the FCFS and Round Robin algorithm.

Firstly, I would like to make the parsing of inputs as simple as possible...

I have a few structures to hold particular information. The program works as follows:

```
my_project FCFS in.file
OR
my_project RR 2 in.file
```

the in.file looks as follows:

```
./Job1.txt
./Job2.txt
./Job3.txt
./Job4.txt
```

So I would like to process this input file and order the jobs.

The text files look as follows.

```
10
1fi
if i < 3 i=i+1 goto 8
3sdkfj
4ksdkk
5kdkfk
6kdkjf
7dkjkfd
if k < 2 k=k+1 goto 2
9dkkf
10dku
if j < 2 j=j+1 goto 2
```

All lines are meaningless except for the first line (indicates starting time of this job) and lines starting with if. i.e. if i < 3 i = i+1 goto 4 means jump to line4 as long as i is less than 3.

So basically at the moment I want to parse input file through the command line like above and order the jobs by start time(first line). I really want to get this step done as efficiently as possible. So far I have written the code below:

```
/* I/O Files */ 
static char *inputFile;
static FILE *input;

/*Scheduled jobs indexed by PID*/
struct job list[20];

/* the next job to schedule */
static struct job *job_next = NULL;

/* Time */
time clock;

/*Initialises job list* /
static void initialise_list(void) {
     for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(job_list); i++) {
        job_list[i].params.pid = -1;
    }
}
```

/** Read and parse input from input file */
static void parse_input(void) {

```
char buffer[BUFSIZ];
unsigned int jobs;

struct job *current;

jobs = 0;

initialise_list();

/** Read input file **/
while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), input)) {
    time start, finish;
    pid job;        

    //if(buffer[0] == '#') {
    //  continue;
    //}

    sscanf(buffer, "Job%d%ld", &job, &start);

        if(start < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Job start time must be greater than or equal to 0,     found %ld.\n", start);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(finish <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Job finish time must be greater than 0, found %ld.      \n", arrival);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        current = &list[job];

        current->parameters.pid = job;
        current->parameters.start = start;


        jobs++;


}    


 int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    /* Open input and output files */
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "in.file") {
            inputFile = argv[i];    
            input = fopen(inputFile,"r");
        }
    }
    if(!inputFile) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    parse_input();
    fclose;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Structures Im using so far.

```
/**
 * Simulation of a process scheduler
*/

#ifndef SCHEDULER_H_
#define SCHEDULER_H_

#include <stddef.h>


/* types */
/** units of time */
typedef long time;
/** process identifier */
typedef int pid;

/** Information about a job of interest to the task scheduler */
struct job_data {

/* pid of this process */
    pid pid;
    /* time process starts */
    time start;
    /* time needed to finish */
    time finish;
    /* time spent processing so far */
    time scheduled;
    /* size of the process */
    size_t size;

};

struct job {

    /* Various parameters used by the scheduler */
    struct job_data parameters;
    /* next job to be scheduled */
    struct job *next;


};
```

In the end, I want to be able to order the jobs in order of starting time so that they are ready to be scheduled by the particular algorithms.

So I  need help on how to pass the input file in.file read the jobs and get the start times and order then by starting 'tick' time i.e. first line of text file.

Any help would be great!!

Comment: I understand my sscanf may not make sense at all... thats largely where I need help...

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your question is (you seemed to have posted a description of what you're doing without asking anything). Because of this my answer can't be an answer, so I'm just going to ramble in a "hopefully useful" way.

In a real system; different tasks start running at different times, block at various times to wait for different things (and are unblocked when whatever they're waiting for happens), and eventually they terminate/exit.

In addition to this there are some advanced features; like explicit task priority control (e.g. "nice()"), grouping tasks, CPU time quotas, etc. I'm not sure that you'd want to worry about these things.

You don't need to implement a minimal subset of BASIC (with variables, loops, etc) to achieve any of this, and attempting to do so will only add pointless complexity. Each file can be a simple linear list. For example:

```
123         ;Starting time
r22         ;Task runs for 22 ticks
s23         ;Task blocks due to "sleep()" for 23 seconds
r4          ;Task runs for 4 ticks
f4          ;Task blocks waiting for "4 units" of file IO (how quickly it unblocks depends on file system load)
r32         ;Task runs for 32 ticks
n8          ;Task blocks until it receives 8 packets from network
r22         ;Task runs for 22 ticks
            ;Task terminates
```

You could add commands to this as you go. For example, start with the "r" command, then add "blocked due to sleep", etc. Eventually you could add things like "task spawns a new task", and "task waits for a child to exit", and "task sends something (via. pipe, socket, whatever) that unblocks another task", etc.

You'll notice that (in my example) all commands are in an "opcode, immediate" form. This is deliberate - it makes parsing simple (get character, get integer, add them both to an array or linked list).

Comment: Im asking how to parse the in.file and essentially do work on the text files stated in that input file... Any help with that?